# Composer branch aliases in different branches

Tags: composer-php

I was wondering if the ***branch-alias*** property of a composer package differs in different branches. e.g: **composer.json** of the `master` branch contains:

`"branch-alias": {
  "dev-master": "3.0.x-dev",
  "dev-foo": "3.1.x-dev
}`

and for the `foo` branch, **composer.json** contains:

`"branch-alias": {
  "dev-master": 3.0.x-dev,
  "dev-foo": "3.2.x-dev,
  "dev-bar": "3.3.x-dev
}`

Now the following questions need to be answered:

- What version will the `foo` branch be aliased as, since the aliases are different in the `master` and the `foo` branch?
- Will the `bar` branch's alias take effect since it is not included in the `master` branch?